# R - retrieve matrix information based on second matrix for paired data

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to retrieve information of a matrix based on another matrix.

Matrix 1 `mat1` is my condition matrix. It is filled with dummies: `0-1`.

```
     idpair 10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
...
```

Matrix 2 `mat2` is the information I need to extract.

```
    idpair 10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "A"    "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"   "f"  
[2,] "A"    "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"   "j"  
[3,] "B"    "g"   "g"   "g"   "g"   "g"   "g"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "g"   "g"  
[4,] "B"    "g"   "g"   "g"   "g"   "g"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "g"   "j"  
...
```

What I need is to create a third matrix that displays the conditional information of matrix 2.

However there is a little complication. 
The data are **paired**. `idpair` is the variable indicating the **pair**.

For example row 1 is paired with row 2 (and vice versa).

What I need is to extract not only the data when `1` appears in `mat1` for the row in question but also the information for the **paired row**.

For example for 3 and 4 are paired. at `11:20` row 4 has a `1` but not row 3. 
What I need is nonetheless extract the info of row 3 at `11:20` because it is paired with row 4.

I need *2* output.

The first ouput should retrieve **all** paired `1`. 
Like this :

```
    idpair 10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "g"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "0"   "0"  
...
```

The second ouput should retrieve just the rows when the pair indicated 1 and the related pair indicated 0. 
So like this :

```
    idpair 10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "A"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "g"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "B"    "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
...
```

Any ideas?

```
mat1 = structure(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), .Dim = c(8L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("idpair", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", 
"11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10")))

mat2 = structure(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "f", "j", 
"g", "g", "h", "c", "b", "j", "f", "j", "g", "g", "h", "d", "i", 
"j", "f", "j", "g", "g", "h", "d", "i", "j", "f", "j", "g", "g", 
"h", "c", "i", "j", "f", "j", "g", "g", "h", "f", "i", "j", "f", 
"j", "g", "b", "h", "c", "i", "j", "f", "j", "b", "b", "h", "c", 
"i", "j", "f", "j", "b", "b", "h", "c", "i", "j", "f", "j", "b", 
"b", "h", "d", "i", "j", "f", "j", "g", "g", "h", "d", "b", "j", 
"f", "j", "g", "j", "h", "c", "b", "j"), .Dim = c(8L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("idpair", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", 
"11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10")))
```

Comment: did you vote down my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start with your data and convert your index matrix `mat1` into a numeric (why do you use characters?):

```
mat1 = cbind.data.frame(mat1[,1], matrix(as.numeric(mat1[,2:12]), ncol = 11))
```

For your first question:

- for each column (`sapply`) I add the two rows of each idpair and take the sign (the `tapply` applies for each idpair, its second argument). 0+0 -> 0, 1+0 -> 1, 0+1 -> 1, 1+1->1 as desired.
- I repeat the rows to get the same structure as before.
- For the output I just copy `mat2` and set to `"0"` everything where `out` is 0.

And here in code:

```
out = sapply(2:12, function(y) tapply(mat1[,y], mat1[,1], function(x) sign(sum(x))))
out = out[rep(1:4, each = 2), ]

out1 = mat2[,-1]
out1[out == 0] = "0"
```

Same for the second question, only that I use `diff` instead of `sum`:

```
out = sapply(2:12, function(y) tapply(mat1[,y], mat1[,1], function(x) sign(diff(x))))
out = out[rep(1:4, each = 2), ]

out2 = mat2[,-1]
out2[out == 0] = "0"
```

Here is your output:

```
> out1
     10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "g"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "0"   "0"  
[5,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[6,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[7,] "b"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "b"  
[8,] "j"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "j"   "j"  
> out2
     10:30 10:40 10:50 11:00 11:10 11:20 11:30 11:40 11:50 12:00 12:10
[1,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "g"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[5,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[6,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[7,] "b"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "b"   "b"  
[8,] "j"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "j"   "j"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with these 2 loops for output 2. 
Does seems to work but quite cumbersome.

```
hid = mat1[,1]
mat1 = mat1[,-1]
mat2 = mat2[,-1]

mat3 = matrix(0, nrow(mat1), ncol(mat1))
```

Basically repeating **1** for the paired-id

```
for(i in 2:nrow(mat1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(mat1)){

    if( hid[i] == hid[i-1] & mat1[i,j] != mat1[i-1,j] ) 
    { mat3[i,j] <- 1 }

    if( hid[i] == hid[i-1] & mat1[i,j] != mat1[i-1,j] ) 
    { mat3[i-1,j] <- 1 }   
  }
}
```

Retreiving the values of `mat2`

```
mat4 = matrix(0, nrow(mat1), ncol(mat1))  

for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(mat1)){

    if( mat3[i,j] == 1){
      mat4[i,j] = mat2[i,j] 
    }     
  }
}
```

Output for `mat4`

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[2,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "g"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "b"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"  
[7,] "b"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "b"   "b"  
[8,] "j"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "j"   "j"
```